# Contactformular only works on localhost

Tags: php, html

I've made a contactformular. It's works fine on localhost, and I receive the email when i send one. Then I uploaded it to my server, and would try it live, and now I doesn't receive any emails, but I'm not getting any errors.

I'm lost, and dont know what to do. Iv'e been trying for hours to make it work, without any luck.

What to do?

Comment: "What to do?" - What about posting some code?

Comment: How is the form sending the email ? php sendmail ?

Comment: Is sendmail running on the server? Or some other SMTP service?

Comment: SteveP - Yes.

Pitchinnate - It might be the server that's the problem. I'll try to talk to my host. :-)